# Kivy Android Save Image

Tags: python, android, image, kivy

I have a simple program with the goal of saving an image to the Android Gallery.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image as KVImage
from kivy.core.image import Image
from os import path


class SITApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text=path.expanduser('~')+'/DCIM/test.jpg', on_press=self.save)

    def save(self, button):
        try:
            Image('test.png').save(path.expanduser('~')+'/DCIM/test.jpg')
        except Exception as e:
            button.text = str(e)


SITApp().run()
```

Right now, the code does not save the image to the specified folder.

Note: The file `test.png` is a picture in the same directory that looks like the following:
[image: Picture]

If anyone can help me save this picture in the Gallery of an Android device, it would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Your `App` will need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Would I just add this to my `buildozer.spec` file, or add it somewhere else?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions). You will also need to include the permission in your `buildozer.spec` as `android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: This still does not move the picture to the Gallery, but thank you for your help

Comment: I suspect your path is incorrect. Try `Image('test.png').save('/sdcard/DCIM/test.jpg')`

Comment: This does move the picture into the `DCIM` folder, but the gallery does not automatically show it

Comment: That is a feature of `Android`. I suggest you post another question about how to get `gallery` to refresh. I have no idea how to do it, but suspect it will involve [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).